# How to best save long Strings to database?

Tags: java, database, json, hibernate

I have a `JSON` file content that can have unlimited size (or limited by the maximal `String` length Integer.MaxValue).

How could I best save this file to database? Just as a `String`? Or are there specific "big" datatypes to store these kinds of data?
I don't want to save the json objects themselve to db, just the whole content.

Comment: What database system?

Comment: Hibernate HSQLDB so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CLOB or BLOB is the choice for most relational databases that I know of.

There's always *some* limit; see your database vendor docs.

"Best" is an interesting term.  Are you well served by encrypting or compressing the data before INSERT?

You won't be able to easily search inside the JSON for a child value.  Does that meet your requirements?

Comment: Probably CLOB will fit my needs. I don't care about compression or inline search.